# How to get actual user email which he/she used for Azure AD SSO login?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I want to get the user emails used for Azure organization on callback action of SSO web login flow.

Could you please advise which property and which API permission should I request for it? I tried `upn`, `preferred_username`, and `email` properties, but as I understand they can differ from the actual email.

Tried multitenant and single-tenant approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the user logs in with their UPN, which is typically (but isn't necessarily) the same as their email address.

The `email` claim should contain the user's email address if the directory is looked after by admins. That's the one you're after.

More information on the default claim set [can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#payload-claims).

More information on how the UPN might be populated, including the approach of using an Alternate ID [can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/plan-connect-userprincipalname).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sometimes I got empty `upn` and `email` fields. Only `preferred_username` present. Is it ok or I misconfigured something on my side?

Comment: That'd depend on the directory setup backing your AAD. Is it synced from on-prem? If so, ask an AD admin. You can also look at the user in the AAD area of the Azure portal - search for them and see which attributes are available. Last thing you could do is use the Graph Explorer (if you have rights) to check the user's profile: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer